# VS Code integrated terminal can't find npm command on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, visual-studio-code

So, I'm using VS Code for my project, both on Windows, where I have no issue, and Linux, where I do.

When typing npm -v in Linux's terminal, the version shows up, so it is correcty installed. If I do the same (or run any other npm command) in VS Code integrated terminal, it says that the command could not be found, as if npm was not installed. Yet it is.

Any idea how I could correct this ?

Thanks so much !

Comment: Well, nevermind, apparently I was missing an update and it's now working like a charm... Not sure if I can delete my question or change its status to solved.

Comment: I had the same problem, switching from the flathup (flatpak) version of vscode to the Pop!_OS (deb) version worked for me.